Val variable keeps changing without any reassignment
I've been working on a basic snake game. The problem which is occuring is that when I run the program, the walls (extraWalls variable) are the ones who keeps changing, whereas the snake's coordinates remain the same.
I thought the error might be because maybe the walls() is being called everytine when the variable is accessed, so i tried to store the value in a separate data class, assign the data class's variable's value to another variable and use that variable's value to be retrieved by the composable. As expected, this too didn't worked at all!
To better demonstrate the problem I reduced my code to the following example code.
ViewModel:
const val gridLength = 21
const val gridWidth = 15
val cellSize = 17.dp

class ExampleViewModel : ViewModel() {
    var coordinates = mutableStateListOf(Pair(14, 14), Pair(15, 14), Pair(16, 14))
        private set

    private var gameGoing by mutableStateOf(true)

    private val eachExtraWallWidthPlusOne = 4
    var extraWalls: List<Pair<Int, Int>> = walls()
        private set

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            while (gameGoing) {
                delay(500) //This controls the snake speed
                coordinatesUpdation()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun coordinatesUpdation() {
        val head: Pair<Int, Int> = coordinates[0]
        val newHead = Pair(head.first - 1, head.second)
        coordinates.add(0, newHead)
        coordinates.removeLast()
    }

    private fun walls(): List<Pair<Int, Int>> {
        val walls = mutableListOf<Pair<Int, Int>>()
        val uniquePositions = mutableSetOf<Pair<Int, Int>>()

        while (uniquePositions.size < 9) {
            var position: Pair<Int, Int>
            do {
                position = Pair(
                    (2 until gridLength).random(),
                    (2 until gridWidth - eachExtraWallWidthPlusOne).random()
                )
            } while (coordinates.any { it == position })

            walls.add(position)
            uniquePositions.add(position)
            repeat(2) {
                position = Pair(position.first, position.second + 1)
                walls.add(position)
                uniquePositions.add(position)
            }
        }
        return uniquePositions.toList()
    }
}

And Composable:
@Composable
fun Display(
    exampleViewModel: ExampleViewModel,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    val colors = difficultGenerateColorGrid(
        coordinates = exampleViewModel.coordinates,
        extraWalls = exampleViewModel.extraWalls
    )
    ColorGrid(colors = colors, modifier = modifier)
}

@Composable
fun ExampleScreen(
    exampleViewModel: ExampleViewModel = ExampleViewModel(),
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    Column(modifier = modifier) {
        Display(exampleViewModel = exampleViewModel, modifier = modifier)

        Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
            Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.KeyboardArrowUp, contentDescription = "Up")
        }
    }
}

fun difficultGenerateColorGrid(
    coordinates: List<Pair<Int, Int>>,
    extraWalls: List<Pair<Int, Int>>
): List<Color> {
    val coloursList: MutableList<Color> = mutableListOf()
    for (i in 1..gridLength) {
        for (j in 1..gridWidth) {
            if (i == 1 || j == 1 || i == gridLength || j == gridWidth/*side walls, no worries*/ || extraWalls.any { it == Pair(i, j) }/*EXTRA WALLS*/) {
                coloursList.add(Color.Red)
            } else if (coordinates.any { it == Pair(i, j) }) {
                coloursList.add(Color.DarkGray)
            } else {
                coloursList.add(Color.White)
            }
        }
    }
    return coloursList
}

@Composable
fun ColorGrid(colors: List<Color>, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    LazyVerticalGrid(
        columns = GridCells.Fixed(gridWidth),
        modifier = modifier
            .size(gridWidth * cellSize, gridLength * cellSize)
    ) {
        items(colors.size) { index ->
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .background(colors[index])
                    .size(cellSize)
            )
        }
    }
}

Full project is at: https://github.com/tauqirnizami/SnakeGame

val variable's can't change. The object may be mutated, but the List<Pair<Int, Int>> you use is immutable so that can also not change. The problem you expeience must be located somehwere else. Please reduce your code to a [mre], one that we can execute and which demonstrates the problem. Be sure to remove everything from your code that is not necessary to reproduce the problem so the code is minimal.

Yes, extraWalls cannot be the problem. Where are you calling the walls() function?

I used extraWalls in the DifficultDisplayGrid() composable (1st composable), and extraWalls uses walls() to initialize its value. And the DifficultDisplayGrid() composable is used by DifficultScreen() composable. I will upload the minimum reproducible example the minute I touch my device! (Currently using mobile phone)

Thanks for the [mre], but please don't just add it, then there is even more code. The idea is to make it as easy as possibe for us to help you. That means that you should remove everything that is not essential to what you are asking. I just edited your question accordingly, please have a look at the revision history to see what I changed to get a feeling for what is necessary and what is superfluous.

I reverted your latest edit. Please do not substantially change the question after an answer was given. The answer given solves the problem, if you have further issues please ask a new question instead.

This is caused by how you retrieve your view model instance:
exampleViewModel: ExampleViewModel = ExampleViewModel(),

On every recomposition this is exectuted again and a new instance of ExampleViewModel is created. The view model's extraWalls property is initialized with walls() which creates some random walls.
So whenever the view model is instantiated you get new, random walls. Since you create a new instance of your view model on every recomposition, you get new walls everytime anything changes in your UI.
This is not how view models are intended to be used. Instead a view model should be bound to a ViewModelStoreOwner, and everytime this owner requests a view model it should get the same instance. The viewModel() function already has all of that conveniently built-in, so you can change your code to this:
exampleViewModel: ExampleViewModel = viewModel(),


But if I remove this extra walls feature, you'd see that the snake's coordinates are updated perfectly. I did thought of what you said, but if that is true, I'm curious why coordinates updation (without this feature) had mo problem and snake was moving perfectly fine throughout the grid (given example only works for upwards direction though). If everytime a new instance is created, then the snake shouldn't move, in other words, its cooridnates should also remain the same as they are variables of the viewModel, shouldn't they?

That probably didn't cause a recomposition so the problem didn't arise. Well, the problem was there all along, but it didn't manifest as undesired behavior. Hard to tell without comparing with the other code.

Try running the newly added code(without extra walls feature), see that the coordinates  variable keeps changing, and the screen is also updated (recomposed) perfectly. (could this be because the coordinates updation function is running on coroutine, hence even when the viewModel instance gets destroyed, the coordinates updation keeps running on background?)

Sorry if I mislead you, that wasn't my intention: I did not mean for you to add the additional code here so that we can compare it, I meant for you to look at your code and compare it. As always, if you have any questions, you can ask them here on StackOverflow, but that would be a new question then.
